# How to create a scoring done on Space Invaders in python

Tags: python-2.7

Here is my code for space invaders, I m supposed to make 2 different enemy ships and have to keep score of the game and also have a destroyable object between the ship and the aliens. I have already gotten most of the program done but cannot understand how to keep score and also have a destroyable object.

Here is my code:

```
from pygame import *
import random


class Sprite:
def __init__(self, xpos, ypos, filename):
    self.x = xpos
    self.y = ypos
    self.bitmap = image.load(filename)
    self.bitmap.set_colorkey((0,0,0))
def set_position(self, xpos, ypos):
    self.x = xpos
    self.y = ypos
def render(self):
    screen.blit(self.bitmap, (self.x, self.y))


def Intersect(s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y):
if (s1_x > s2_x - 32) and (s1_x < s2_x + 32) and (s1_y > s2_y - 32) and (s1_y < s2_y+3       
    return 1
else:
    return 0
init()
screen = display.set_mode((640,480))
key.set_repeat(1, 1)
display.set_caption('PyInvaders')
backdrop = image.load('background.bmp')


enemies = []

x = 0

for count in range(10):
enemies.append(Sprite(50 * x + 50, 50, 'alien.bmp'))
x += 1
    enemies.append(Sprite(25 * x + 50, 25, 'alien2.bmp'))
x += 1

hero = Sprite(20, 400, 'hero.bmp')
ourmissile = Sprite(0, 480, 'heromissile.bmp')
enemymissile = Sprite(0, 480, 'alienmissile.bmp')


quit = 0
enemyspeed = 3

while quit == 0:
screen.blit(backdrop, (0, 0))


for count in range(len(enemies)):
    enemies[count].x += + enemyspeed
    enemies[count].render()

if enemies[len(enemies)-1].x > 590:
    enemyspeed = -3
    for count in range(len(enemies)):
        enemies[count].y += 5

if enemies[0].x < 10:
    enemyspeed = 3
    for count in range(len(enemies)):
        enemies[count].y += 5

if ourmissile.y < 479 and ourmissile.y > 0:
    ourmissile.render()
    ourmissile.y -= 5

if enemymissile.y >= 480 and len(enemies) > 0:
    enemymissile.x = enemies[random.randint(0, len(enemies) - 1)].x
    enemymissile.y = enemies[0].y



if Intersect(hero.x, hero.y, enemymissile.x, enemymissile.y):
    quit = 1

for count in range(0, len(enemies)):
    if Intersect(ourmissile.x, ourmissile.y, enemies[count].x, enemies[count].y):
        del enemies[count]
        break

if len(enemies) == 0:
    quit = 1


for ourevent in event.get():
    if ourevent.type == QUIT:
        quit = 1
    if ourevent.type == KEYDOWN:
        if ourevent.key == K_RIGHT and hero.x < 590:
            hero.x += 5
        if ourevent.key == K_LEFT and hero.x > 10:
            hero.x -= 5
        if ourevent.key == K_SPACE:
            ourmissile.x = hero.x
            ourmissile.y = hero.y


enemymissile.render()
enemymissile.y += 5

hero.render()

display.update()
time.delay(5)
```

Comment: You can implement a health property for the destroyable objects. As for the score, I assume you have a `Player` class or something similar. I would keep track of the score in there.

Comment: Also, please mind the indent levels. Especially when posting Python ;].

Comment: so how would the code for for the destroyable object and the scoring go, for example how would i set it up?

Comment: As I would have done it, the score would be stored as a property of my class `Player` (the class I would use to represent the user). Basically, you substract/add to this variable and refresh the display during each loop. As for the health points of entities (players, obstacles, enemies), all you need is a property in each object to keep track of health points. Once that amount reach 0, you know that the unit is supposedly dead.

Comment: However, health points is not the good way to go for obstacles within a Space Invader remake. I believe that a pixel-based approach is recommended.